# Use of “As well” in the beginning of a sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is it improper to start a sentence with “As well,” to mean “In addition”? 
Some grammar books say “As well,” should be used only at the end of the sentence. Is it so?

Comment: Sentence-initial _Too,_ and _Plus,_ also seem to be more idiomatic in some regions than in others.

Answer (score 2):

According to Bryan Garner's [*Modern English Usage*](https://books.google.de/books?id=l2LmCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=%22As%20well%22%20beginning%20sentence%20Canadian&source=bl&ots=Zfiz3_1n4Z&sig=ytldHrwjcWP1NCdP0pzDqYPp-E4&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD-6zmmKTZAhWFCCwKHaIhCGYQ6AEwBXoECA0QAQ#v=onepage&q=%22As%20well%22%20beginning%20sentence%20Canadian&f=false) (2016), initial *as well* meaning "also, in addition, moreover," is standard Canadian usage, but usually considered poor style elsewhere. So if you're Canadian or writing for a Canadian readership, feel free to use it. If not, it would be best in some other position in the sentence.

Comment: Why did you not tell us what your search engines and on-line thesauruses told you, please?

"As well" is well able to start a sentence in many contexts, and unreasonable in many others.

As so often, here, context is all…

Comment: Right. As long as those contexts are in the land of Molson and Tim Horton. There was also a brief essay on the OED website on Canadian English that mentioned initial _As well_ as a characteristic of Canadian English as well. Oh, look! I'm not Canadian and I put it at the end of the sentence. Note this is not _as well as_.

Answer (score 0):

The use of “As well” as an initial conjunction is unique to Ontario natives. I’d never encountered that usage anywhere in print or in speech in Western Canada during the four decades preceding 2003, until a young editor from Toronto began working in our Japanese translation office in Vancouver. I’m afraid that Texas-born Garner has mistakenly generalized what’s recently become common in populous Southern Ontario as “Canadian.”

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).